# Arduino Analog joystick button looks always pressed after the first time

Tags: button, arduino-ide, lcd, joystick

I have problems in the BrainTest() function
When I load it the starting text doesn't appear on the LCD, it goes straight to the:

> if (button == 0) {
>
> > lcd.clear();
> >
> > lcd.setCursor(0,0);
> >
> > lcd.print("Let's start");
> >
> > delay (1400);
> >
> > lcd.clear();
> >
> > lcd.setCursor(0,0);
> >
> > lcd.print("test");
>
> }

I also think there is a problem to select either "Yes" or "No" at the beginning of the function.

Any help would be appreciated...

```cpp
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>

// Arduino pins number
const int SW_pin = 2; // digital pin connected to switch output
const int X_pin = 0; // analog pin connected to X output
const int Y_pin = 1; // analog pin connected to Y output
const int LCD_RS = 7;
const int LCD_Enable = 8;
const int LCD_D4 = 9;
const int LCD_D5 = 10;
const int LCD_D6 = 11;
const int LCD_D7 = 12;
LiquidCrystal lcd(LCD_RS, LCD_Enable, LCD_D4, LCD_D5, LCD_D6, LCD_D7);

// Basic vars
int none = 0;
String Apps[3] = {"App select","Credits","Test your brain"};
int CurrentApp = 0;
int Yaxis = 1;
int Xaxis = 1;
int HiCh = 0;
int button;
int JXaxis;
int JYaxis;
int MaxHi;


void AppSelect() {  //          APPSELECT
  lcd.setCursor(0,0);
  lcd.print("App select menu");
  lcd.setCursor(0,1);
  lcd.print(Apps[HiCh]);
  if (button == 0) {
    SelectApp();
  }
  if (JYaxis <= 2) {
    if (HiCh != 0) {
      HiCh = HiCh - 1;
      lcd.clear();
      lcd.setCursor(0,1);
      lcd.print(Apps[HiCh]);
      delay(300);
    }
  }
  if (JYaxis >= 7) {
    if (HiCh != 1) {
      HiCh = HiCh + 1;
      lcd.clear();
      lcd.setCursor(0,1);
      lcd.print(Apps[HiCh]);
      delay(300);
    }
  }
}

void Credits() {  //          CREDITS
  MaxHi = 0;
  Serial.print("- Credits app loading \n");
  lcd.clear();
  lcd.setCursor(9,0);
  lcd.print("Credits");
  lcd.setCursor(0,1);
  lcd.print("Made by Alexandre Bergeron");
  Serial.print("- Credits app loaded \n");
  delay(1300);
  lcd.scrollDisplayLeft();
  delay(600);
  lcd.scrollDisplayLeft();
  delay(600);
  lcd.scrollDisplayLeft();
  delay(600);
  lcd.scrollDisplayLeft();
  delay(600);
  lcd.scrollDisplayLeft();
  delay(600);
  lcd.scrollDisplayLeft();
  delay(600);
  lcd.scrollDisplayLeft();
  delay(600);
  lcd.scrollDisplayLeft();
  delay(600);
  lcd.scrollDisplayLeft();
  delay(600);
  lcd.scrollDisplayLeft();
  delay(600);
  lcd.scrollDisplayLeft();
  delay(600);
  lcd.scrollDisplayLeft();
  delay(1500);
  CurrentApp = 0;
  lcd.clear();
}


void BrainTest() {  //          BRAINTEST
  MaxHi = 1;
  HiCh = 0;
  lcd.clear();
  lcd.setCursor(0,0);
  lcd.print("Are you ready?");
  lcd.setCursor(0,1);
  lcd.print("Yes");
  for (;;) {
    button = digitalRead(SW_pin);
    if (HiCh == 0) {
      lcd.setCursor(0,1);
      lcd.print("Yes");
      if (button == 0) {
        lcd.clear();
        lcd.setCursor(0,0);
        lcd.print("Let's start");
        delay (1400);
        lcd.clear();
        lcd.setCursor(0,0);
        lcd.print("done");
      }
    }
    if (HiCh == 1) {
      lcd.setCursor(0,1);
      lcd.print("No");
      if (button == 0) {
        CurrentApp = 0;
      }
    }
    break;
  }
}


void setup() {  //          SETUP
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.print("[2J");
  Serial.print("  Serial Monitor opened \n \n");
  // set up the LCD's number of columns and rows:
  lcd.begin(16, 2);
  Serial.print("- App selector menu \n");
  pinMode(SW_pin, INPUT);
  digitalWrite(SW_pin, HIGH);
}


void SelectApp() {  //          SELECTAPP
  switch (HiCh) {
    case (0):
      CurrentApp = 0;
      AppSelect();
      break;
    case (1):
      CurrentApp = 1;
      Credits();
      break;
    case (2):
      CurrentApp = 2;
      BrainTest();
      break;
    default:
      lcd.clear();
      lcd.setCursor(0,0);
      lcd.print("Error");
      Serial.print("- App loading error \n");
      break;
  }
}


void loop() {  //          LOOP
  Serial.print(HiCh);
  button = digitalRead(SW_pin);
  int JYaxis = analogRead(Y_pin) / 128;
  int JXaxis = analogRead(X_pin) / 128;
  if (JYaxis >= 7) {
    if (HiCh != 0) {
      HiCh = HiCh - 1;
      delay(300);
    }
  }
  if (JYaxis <= 2) {
    if (HiCh != MaxHi) {
      HiCh = HiCh + 1;
      delay(300);
    }
  }
  if (CurrentApp == 0) { 
    MaxHi = 2;
    lcd.setCursor(0,0);
    lcd.print("App select menu");
    lcd.setCursor(0,1);
    lcd.print(Apps[HiCh]);
    if (button == 0) {
      SelectApp();
    }
    if (JYaxis >= 7) {
      if (HiCh != 0) {
        lcd.clear();
        lcd.setCursor(0,0);
        lcd.print("App select menu");
        lcd.setCursor(0,1);
        lcd.print(Apps[HiCh]);
        delay(300);
      }
    }
    if (JYaxis <= 2) {
      if (HiCh != 2) {
        lcd.clear();
        lcd.setCursor(0,0);
        lcd.print("App select menu");
        lcd.setCursor(0,1);
        lcd.print(Apps[HiCh]);
        delay(300);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If you think I should change anything in the question tell me and I'll correct it.
Also if you fount other problems or upgrades to my code just tell me out and I'll consider them.

> .

Now the SelectApp(); function is working well but in the BrainTest(); function the first question isn't working.
I cannot switch between answers...

Here's the new code

```cpp
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>

// Arduino pins number
const int SW_pin = 2; // digital pin connected to switch output
const int X_pin = 0; // analog pin connected to X output
const int Y_pin = 1; // analog pin connected to Y output
const int LCD_RS = 7;
const int LCD_Enable = 8;
const int LCD_D4 = 9;
const int LCD_D5 = 10;
const int LCD_D6 = 11;
const int LCD_D7 = 12;
LiquidCrystal lcd(LCD_RS, LCD_Enable, LCD_D4, LCD_D5, LCD_D6, LCD_D7);

// Basic vars
int none = 0;
String Apps[3] = {"App select","Credits","Test your brain"};
int CurrentApp = 0;
int Yaxis = 1;
int Xaxis = 1;
int HiCh = 0;
int button;
int JXaxis;
int JYaxis;
int MaxHi;


void AppSelect() {  //          APPSELECT
  lcd.setCursor(0,0);
  lcd.print("App select menu");
  lcd.setCursor(0,1);
  lcd.print(Apps[HiCh]);
  if (button == 0) {
    SelectApp();
  }
  if (JYaxis <= 2) {
    if (HiCh != 0) {
      HiCh = HiCh - 1;
      lcd.clear();
      lcd.setCursor(0,1);
      lcd.print(Apps[HiCh]);
      delay(300);
    }
  }
  if (JYaxis >= 7) {
    if (HiCh != 1) {
      HiCh = HiCh + 1;
      lcd.clear();
      lcd.setCursor(0,1);
      lcd.print(Apps[HiCh]);
      delay(300);
    }
  }
}

void Credits() {  //          CREDITS
  MaxHi = 0;
  Serial.print("- Credits app loading \n");
  lcd.clear();
  lcd.setCursor(9,0);
  lcd.print("Credits");
  lcd.setCursor(0,1);
  lcd.print("Made by Alexandre Bergeron");
  Serial.print("- Credits app loaded \n");
  delay(1300);
  lcd.scrollDisplayLeft();
  delay(600);
  lcd.scrollDisplayLeft();
  delay(600);
  lcd.scrollDisplayLeft();
  delay(600);
  lcd.scrollDisplayLeft();
  delay(600);
  lcd.scrollDisplayLeft();
  delay(600);
  lcd.scrollDisplayLeft();
  delay(600);
  lcd.scrollDisplayLeft();
  delay(600);
  lcd.scrollDisplayLeft();
  delay(600);
  lcd.scrollDisplayLeft();
  delay(600);
  lcd.scrollDisplayLeft();
  delay(600);
  lcd.scrollDisplayLeft();
  delay(600);
  lcd.scrollDisplayLeft();
  delay(1500);
  CurrentApp = 0;
  lcd.clear();
}


void BrainTest() {  //          BRAINTEST
  MaxHi = 1;
  HiCh = 0;
  lcd.clear();
  lcd.setCursor(0,0);
  lcd.print("Are you ready?");
  lcd.setCursor(0,1);
  lcd.print("Yes");
  for (;;) {
    button = digitalRead(SW_pin);
    if (HiCh == 0) {
      lcd.clear();
      lcd.setCursor(0,0);
      lcd.print("Are you ready?");
      lcd.setCursor(0,1);
      lcd.print("Yes");
      if (button == 0) {
        lcd.clear();
        lcd.setCursor(0,0);
        lcd.print("Let's start");
        delay (1400);
        lcd.clear();
        lcd.setCursor(0,0);
        lcd.print("done");
      }
    }
    if (HiCh == 1) {
      lcd.clear();
      lcd.setCursor(0,0);
      lcd.print("Are you ready?");
      lcd.setCursor(0,1);
      lcd.print("No");
      if (button == 0) {
        CurrentApp = 0;
      }
    }
    break;
  }
}


void setup() {  //          SETUP
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.print("[2J");
  Serial.print("  Serial Monitor opened \n \n");
  // set up the LCD's number of columns and rows:
  lcd.begin(16, 2);
  Serial.print("- App selector menu \n");
  pinMode(SW_pin, INPUT);
  digitalWrite(SW_pin, HIGH);
}


void SelectApp() {  //          SELECTAPP
  switch (HiCh) {
    case (0):
      CurrentApp = 0;
      AppSelect();
      break;
    case (1):
      CurrentApp = 1;
      Credits();
      break;
    case (2):
      CurrentApp = 2;
      BrainTest();
      break;
    default:
      lcd.clear();
      lcd.setCursor(0,0);
      lcd.print("Error");
      Serial.print("- App loading error \n");
      break;
  }
}


void loop() {  //          LOOP
  Serial.print(HiCh);
  button = digitalRead(SW_pin);
  int JYaxis = analogRead(Y_pin) / 128;
  int JXaxis = analogRead(X_pin) / 128;
  if (JYaxis >= 7) {
    if (HiCh != 0) {
      HiCh = HiCh - 1;
  delay(300);
    }
  }
  if (JYaxis <= 2) {
    if (HiCh != MaxHi) {
      HiCh = HiCh + 1;
      delay(300);
    }
  }
  if (CurrentApp == 0) { 
    MaxHi = 2;
    lcd.setCursor(0,0);
    lcd.print("App select menu");
    lcd.setCursor(0,1);
    lcd.print(Apps[HiCh]);
    if (button == 0) {
      while (button == 0) {
        delay (200);
        break;
      }
      SelectApp();
    }
    if (JYaxis >= 7) {
      if (HiCh != 0) {
        lcd.clear();
        lcd.setCursor(0,0);
        lcd.print("App select menu");
        lcd.setCursor(0,1);
        lcd.print(Apps[HiCh]);
        delay(300);
      }
    }
    if (JYaxis <= 2) {
      if (HiCh != 2) {
        lcd.clear();
        lcd.setCursor(0,0);
        lcd.print("App select menu");
        lcd.setCursor(0,1);
        lcd.print(Apps[HiCh]);
        delay(300);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Why do you have `for (;;) {  ...  ; break; }`, here? Anyway, you don't understand how fast it is and you have to use some loops for switch detection. And possibly debouncing too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are handling the button completely wrong. You have microseconds to release button after you select the app. So it looks like it's pressed, because it is. You never checked if it was ever released.

I'd recommend to start with super simple program: *Count how many times the button was pressed and send it to the serial.*

You can't create anything like you're trying to, until you can make this simple button press counter working.

Comment: Thanks, I’ll try this and I will get back to you

Comment: I tried to put a delay(200); after the calling of selectapp(); in the loop function but it’s still happening

Comment: Where do you suggest me to put the delay

Comment: I suggest you to wait until the button is actually released before you go into the subprogram selection.

Comment: How would you do that?

Comment: @Spyro999 How? Like  `while (digitalRead(SW_pin) == LOW) delay(10);` to wait for release? But it won't work if you place it after the selectApp. The brainTest is called inside of the selectApp so placing it after is too late

Comment: If I do not write what you said it loads the credits app and if I do it simply just does nothing and the joystick stop working

Comment: Now I just added a break statement in the while loop and it works

Comment: I updated the question with my new problem and the updated code

Comment: @Spyro999 Again. *Start with something simple.* Until you don't understand the difference between: `while (digitalRead(SW_pin) == LOW) { delay(10); }` and `button = digitalRead(SW_pin); while (button == LOW) { delay(10); }` it's impossible to do something "difficult". The `button` in second snippet never ever change as it never ever checks real value on the input pin.

Comment: Now all the buttons are working well but should I do this with the xaxis and the yaxis?

Comment: @Spyro999 Those should be another question as this one is just about the button.